# i18n Attaching variable to translation string

Tags: ember.js, internationalization, handlebars.js

I am currently using i18n to translate strings and I'm looking for a way to attach a variable onto the path.

This variable could be about 8 different values and each need a different translation. My locale files already include the translations but I don't know how to add my variable onto the translation path. I **don't** think [variable interpolation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#passing-variables-to-translations) helps me here.

```
content.state //variable
t ('.state') //locale path
```

I'm looking for a way to add the content.state variable to the end of the locale path so that it translates depending on what content.state is. Currently my only solution is a large if/else covering all the states.

Solved: I was trying to find a way to add a variable to the locale path inside handlebars and ended up using the concat helper.

```
{{ t (concat "state." content.state)}}
```

Answer (score 15):

You can do that like this (example):

```js
I18n.t('helpers.links.add', { variable: "Your Variable Value" })
```

then, on your translation file (yml):

```
helpers:
  links:
    add: "Add %{variable}"
```

That way, in my example, the output would be: Add Your Variable Value.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this too. My problem was to be able to add a variable into the link to the translation. I managed it perfectly using the context.

Let's say you want to show "English" and "French" when "en" and "fr" are returned from your back-end.

In your translation files (en.json and fr.json) add the context:

```
{
  ...
  "language_en":"English",
  "language_fr":"French",
  ...
}
```

And in your front-end, saying your variable name is **objectLanguage**, use the context with:

```
t('language', { context: objectLanguage })
```

i18next will look to the specific context and render corretly "English" or "French"!

Documentation can be find [here](https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/context).

**EDIT:** even easier, you can use the quote marks, if you code:

```
t(`language.${objectLanguage}.label`)
```

To point to the links:

```
{
  ...
  "language.en.label":"English",
  "language.fr.label":"French",
  ...
}
```

It will works fine too.

Hop this can help someone.